# Need VBA to German text to speech

Tags: vba, text-to-speech

I am able to translate English text to German, but am unable to have the German text actually spoken in German.  The TTS voices are not pronouncing the German words correctly.  Google translate has correct pronunciation but I don't know how to call in from Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2):

Download the german TTS version [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Speak-feature-with-Multilingual-TTS-e522a4f2-37cb-492b-be6a-8997d23dfe70)

It should work.

Edit:
Here is how you check the available voices that you have:
(the code is from [here](http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/make-excel-talk-with-application-speech-speak-vba/), I have made a late binding, so it works without adding libraries)

```
Option Explicit


    Sub AvailableVoices()

        Dim i           As Long
        Dim voc         As Object

        Set voc = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

        Debug.Print voc.GetVoices.Count & " available voices:"

        For i = 0 To voc.GetVoices.Count - 1
            Set voc.Voice = voc.GetVoices.Item(i)
            Debug.Print " " & i & " - " & voc.Voice.GetDescription
            voc.Speak "test audio"
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: I had previously downloaded t and installed he German TTS file.  How do I call it from VBA ?  I can not find any samples.  Thanks

Comment: @GaryE - check this link, it is well explained - http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/make-excel-talk-with-application-speech-speak-vba/